# Trying to create multiple shakes using shake.js

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, dom-events

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to get an alert to show up every time the phone is shaken. But I keep getting an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of undefined

Is it because it doesn't know what 'shake' is? The reason for more than one shake is because I'll be adding different animations depending on what shake its on.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <title>Shake animation</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body {
background: #E9E9E9; 
color: #333; 
font: 1em/1.3em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; /* 16px /    21px */
text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 0 1px 0;
text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shake.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="answerListener" id="answer1"></div>
       <div class="answerListener" id="answer2"></div>
       <div class="answerListener" id="answer3"></div>
       <div class="answerListener" id="answer4"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {


   var answer = document.getElementsByClassName('answerListener');
   var current = 1;

   for (i = 0; answer.length; i++) {
   answer[i].addEventListener('shake', function() {

   if (current == 1) {
      alert('shake1');
   }
   if (current == 2) {
      alert('shake2');
   }
   if (current == 3) {
      alert('shake3');
   }
   if (current == 4) {
      alert('shake4');
   }
   current = current + 1;
   }, false);
}   
};

</script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good except for one small problem: your `for` loop does not terminate:

```
for (i = 0; answer.length; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
```

You are getting the error because once `i` exceeds `answer.length`, `answer[i]` is undefined and therefore `answer[i].addEventListener` is attempting to call the method of a non-existing element.

Good luck.